# Draw a tikz complete 12 nodes directed graph

Tags: graphs, tikz-graphdrawing, music

I need to draw a graph based on music theory using Tikz. As said in the titled, it's a 12 node, complete, directed graph. Nodes must be labeled according to musical notes and edges must be labeled according to musical intervals. I have a hand drawing example of what I need: [image: Graph example]

On the image I've only draw some edges because it would get pretty messy drawing every single edge. But it should be complete, as said before.

I hope it's possible to label every edge like that. I also hope my question is clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are correct when you say that it gets quite messy. The way I've drawn it with straight lines after tritones lines start to double up so instead I suggest drawing two separate graphs for major seconds to tritones and then tritones to major sevenths.

So the first, major seconds to tritones, graph would give
[image: connected graph between the 12 musical notes showing intervals from minor seconds to tritones]

Which is given by

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=20]{standalone}

\usepackage{contour}  % Add halo around node text for readability

\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}  % nodes placed in foreground
\pgfsetlayers{main,foreground}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{7}

\contourlength{1.2pt}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzset{note/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1.75cm}}
        \tikzset{edge/.style={->, >=latex}}
        
        \node[note] (C) at (0:\R) {C};
        \node[note] (Db) at (-30:\R) {C\#/Db};
        \node[note] (D) at (-60:\R) {D};
        \node[note] (Eb) at (-90:\R) {D\#/Eb};
        \node[note] (E) at (-120:\R) {E};
        \node[note] (F) at (-150:\R) {F};
        \node[note] (Gb) at (-180:\R) {F\#/Gb};
        \node[note] (G) at (-210:\R) {G};
        \node[note] (Ab) at (-240:\R) {G\#/Ab};
        \node[note] (A) at (-270:\R) {A};
        \node[note] (Bb) at (-300:\R) {A\#/Bb};
        \node[note] (B) at (-330:\R) {B};
        
        % Minor seconds
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/Db, Db/D, D/Eb, Eb/E, E/F, F/Gb, Gb/G, G/Ab, Ab/A, A/Bb, Bb/B, B/C} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                 \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{2m}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        
        % Major seconds
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/D, Db/Eb, D/E, Eb/F, E/Gb, F/G, Gb/Ab, G/A, Ab/Bb, A/B, Bb/C, B/Db} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{2M}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        
        % Minor thirds
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/Eb, Db/E, D/F, Eb/Gb, E/G, F/Ab, Gb/A, G/Bb, Ab/B, A/C, Bb/Db, B/D} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{3m}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        
        % Major thirds
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/E, Db/F, D/Gb, Eb/G, E/Ab, F/A, Gb/Bb, G/B, Ab/C, A/Db, Bb/D, B/Eb} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                 \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{3M}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        
        % Perfect Fourths
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/F, Db/Gb, D/G, Eb/Ab, E/A, F/Bb, Gb/B, G/C, Ab/Db, A/D, Bb/Eb, B/E} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                 \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{4}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
        
        % Tritones
        \foreach \i/\j in {C/Gb, Db/G, D/Ab, Eb/A, E/Bb, F/B, Gb/C, G/Db, Ab/D, A/Eb, Bb/E, B/Eb} {
            \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
            \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
                 \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{T}};
            \end{pgfonlayer}
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graph for tritones to major sevenths is then
[image: connected graph between the 12 musical notes showing intervals from tritones to major sevenths]
which is given by the following using the same preamble

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{note/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1.75cm}}
    \tikzset{edge/.style={<-, >=latex}}
    
    \node[note] (C) at (0:\R) {C};
    \node[note] (Db) at (-30:\R) {C\#/Db};
    \node[note] (D) at (-60:\R) {D};
    \node[note] (Eb) at (-90:\R) {D\#/Eb};
    \node[note] (E) at (-120:\R) {E};
    \node[note] (F) at (-150:\R) {F};
    \node[note] (Gb) at (-180:\R) {F\#/Gb};
    \node[note] (G) at (-210:\R) {G};
    \node[note] (Ab) at (-240:\R) {G\#/Ab};
    \node[note] (A) at (-270:\R) {A};
    \node[note] (Bb) at (-300:\R) {A\#/Bb};
    \node[note] (B) at (-330:\R) {B};
    
    % Major sevenths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Db, Db/D, D/Eb, Eb/E, E/F, F/Gb, Gb/G, G/Ab, Ab/A, A/Bb, Bb/B, B/C} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
             \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{7M}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    
    % Minor sevenths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/D, Db/Eb, D/E, Eb/F, E/Gb, F/G, Gb/Ab, G/A, Ab/Bb, A/B, Bb/C, B/Db} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{7m}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    
    % Major sixths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Eb, Db/E, D/F, Eb/Gb, E/G, F/Ab, Gb/A, G/Bb, Ab/B, A/C, Bb/Db, B/D} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
            \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{6M}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    
    % Minor Sixths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/E, Db/F, D/Gb, Eb/G, E/Ab, F/A, Gb/Bb, G/B, Ab/C, A/Db, Bb/D, B/Eb} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
             \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{6m}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    
    % Perfect Fifths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/F, Db/Gb, D/G, Eb/Ab, E/A, F/Bb, Gb/B, G/C, Ab/Db, A/D, Bb/Eb, B/E} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
             \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{5}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
    
    % Tritones
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Gb, Db/G, D/Ab, Eb/A, E/Bb, F/B, Gb/C, G/Db, Ab/D, A/Eb, Bb/E, B/Eb} {
        \draw[edge] (\i) -- (\j);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{foreground}
             \path (\i) -- (\j) node[midway] {\contour{white}{T}};
        \end{pgfonlayer}
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Personally however I think that this is still quite messy, I don't know what your using this for but personally I would go with a colour coding scheme. You could also use dashed/dotted lines etc. for black and white printing/colour blind friendly versions. The following graph gives the forward direction of the arrow and then in brackets (parentheses for you Americans) the backwards direction:

[image: connected graph between the 12 musical notes showing intervals in rainbow]

This is given by

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzset{note/.style={draw, circle, minimum size=1.75cm}}
    \tikzset{edge/.style={->, >=latex}}
    
    \node[note] (C) at (0:\R) {C};
    \node[note] (Db) at (-30:\R) {C\#/Db};
    \node[note] (D) at (-60:\R) {D};
    \node[note] (Eb) at (-90:\R) {D\#/Eb};
    \node[note] (E) at (-120:\R) {E};
    \node[note] (F) at (-150:\R) {F};
    \node[note] (Gb) at (-180:\R) {F\#/Gb};
    \node[note] (G) at (-210:\R) {G};
    \node[note] (Ab) at (-240:\R) {G\#/Ab};
    \node[note] (A) at (-270:\R) {A};
    \node[note] (Bb) at (-300:\R) {A\#/Bb};
    \node[note] (B) at (-330:\R) {B};
    
    % Minor seconds
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Db, Db/D, D/Eb, Eb/E, E/F, F/Gb, Gb/G, G/Ab, Ab/A, A/Bb, Bb/B, B/C} {
        \draw[edge, red] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    
    % Major seconds
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/D, Db/Eb, D/E, Eb/F, E/Gb, F/G, Gb/Ab, G/A, Ab/Bb, A/B, Bb/C, B/Db} {
        \draw[edge, orange] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    
    % Minor thirds
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Eb, Db/E, D/F, Eb/Gb, E/G, F/Ab, Gb/A, G/Bb, Ab/B, A/C, Bb/Db, B/D} {
        \draw[edge, yellow] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    
    % Major thirds
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/E, Db/F, D/Gb, Eb/G, E/Ab, F/A, Gb/Bb, G/B, Ab/C, A/Db, Bb/D, B/Eb} {
        \draw[edge, green] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    
    % Perfect Fourths
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/F, Db/Gb, D/G, Eb/Ab, E/A, F/Bb, Gb/B, G/C, Ab/Db, A/D, Bb/Eb, B/E} {
        \draw[edge, blue] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    
    % Tritones
    \foreach \i/\j in {C/Gb, Db/G, D/Ab, Eb/A, E/Bb, F/B, Gb/C, G/Db, Ab/D, A/Eb, Bb/E, B/Eb} {
        \draw[edge, red!50!blue] (\i) -- (\j);
    }
    \foreach \y/\col/\lab in {1/red/Minor Second (Major Seventh), 2/orange/Major Second (Minor Seventh), 3/yellow/Minor Third (Major Sixth), 4/green/Major Third (Minor Sixth), 5/blue/Perfect Fourth (Perfect Fifth), 6/red!50!blue/Tritone} {
        \draw[ultra thick, color=\col] (-3, -\R-1-\y) -- (-2, -\R-1-\y) node[right, black] {\lab};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks Willoughby! That's exactly what I was looking for. Loved your preoccupation with color blind people!